# color picker magnifying glass missing

Tags: macos, color

I am running Yosemite and the color picker is supposed to have a magnifying glass. Except I do not have this and cannot turn it on. I do not see the magnifying glass as shown between the tool bar and the colour wheel.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is now a more appropriate Pipette icon.

You can see it at the bottom of the picker

[image]